# Parsing a string as an array in Excel 2010 (without VBscript)

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, excel-2010

I've got a whole bunch of cells containing arbitrary length arrays stored as semicolon-delimited strings, ranging in length from 1 to 65 entries, like:

- pcmsh15(232);pcmsh16(232);pcmsh17(136);
- pcmsh12(40);
- pcmsh12(40);
- pcmsh12(5);pcmsh15(20);

**I want a way to sum up the numbers in the parenthesis in Excel 2010 without using VBA, keeping in mind that they are *arbitrary length* strings, each contained in their own cell.**

I've currently got a VBA function that I wrote that sums the numbers in parenthesis, but it's slowing my spreadsheet down. I know I can use Excel's SUBSTITUTE function to turn the semi-colon delimited arrays into something resembling Excel's internal array format, like

```
="{"&SUBSTITUTE([@[data]],";",",")&"}"
```

But unfortunately, Excel won't parse that as an array in SUM or COUNTIF, only as a string. One workaround I found makes a named range that references the cell with a string-formatted array, but since I also have an arbitrary number of these arrays in cells, I can't go naming every single cell.

Is something like this possible in "pure" excel functions?

Comment: When entering array formulas you don't type the { }  so ="{"&...&"}" does not make it an array.  To enter an array formula, tpye it without {} and press Ctrl-Shit-Enter

Comment: Are your "Arrays" in a single cell or several cells? ie is `pcmsh15(232);pcmsh16(232);pcmsh17(136);` in one cell or three?

Comment: Also to Chris Neilson's question, is there a limit to the number of terms that require summing within the string? There is a way as long as there is some idea on the number of terms.

Comment: I've edited my question with some clarification. @chris: the "arrays" are in one cell. @lionz: Most of the arrays are around 6 in length, but I've gotten some that have 65 entries, so I can't really depend on a function with a hard limit. The source data I have to work with comes from a CSV file, so that's why I have to deal with these weird arrays :/

Comment: If your VBA function is slowing down your spreadsheet, then I dare to venture that it isn't optimised. Why don't you show it to us so we can fix that.

Comment: @jean-francois: My other problem with VBA is having to use macros at all, which brings the dreaded "macros disabled" bar, and that freaks some people out. However, I'd much rather have a well written and readable VBA function than a convoluted mess of native excel functions, if that's what it comes to. Here's my VBA code that performs the equivalent calculation: http://pastebin.com/gxqfzANw

Comment: @blendmaster: Your VBA function looks mostly fine, actually. I got a marginal improvement by just saying `machine = Mid(machine, InStr(1, machine, "("))` i.e. leaving the parentheses there, but the real overhead is in the interaction between the sheet and VBA. I'm afraid there's little improvement to be had!

Comment: @chris neilsen: I can't find the "Shit" key! What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @blendmaster, re: the speed of your VBA function. If it's really an issue, you can try two more things, but I don't know if either would help that much: 1) Use a regular expression to pull the numbers of interest out all at once. 2) Pass in a whole array of strings to parse, do them all, and then return an array of sums back from a single call to your UDF.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with no VBA involved. The method is kind of ridiculous, though. But, just for fun...

In cell `B4` I put one of the strings you want to "parse":

```
B4:  pcmsh15(232);pcmsh16(232);pcmsh17(136);
```

Then I put the following formulas in the cells indicated:

```
B6:  =SUBSTITUTE(B4,"pcmsh", """dummy")
B8:  =SUBSTITUTE(B6,"(",""";")
B10: =SUBSTITUTE(B8,")","")
B12: =MID(B10, 1, LEN(B10)-1)
B14: ="{"&B12&"}"
```

That transforms the starting text into a text representation of a legal Excel array:

```
B14: {"dummy15";232;"dummy16";232;"dummy17";136}
```

You can make Excel evaluate that string and return an actual array with the following trick. Create a named formula that we'll call `eval_left`. Make sure cell `C14` is selected when you create the named formula:

```
=EVALUATE(B14)
```

Note that the formula uses a relative reference, so if you use that name from a cell other than `C14`, you'll see that the `B14` has changed to whatever cell is just to the left.

This uses the old Excel 4 macro function `EVALUATE`, which takes a string and returns the value that that string represents. Now we can put a final formula in cell `C14`:

```
C14: =SUM(eval_left)
```

Since `SUM` ignores non-numeric strings, you get the answer you want, with no VBA. (You do still get the macro warning though, because of the use of `EVALUATE`.)

Like I said, I consider this a just-for-fun curiousity. You're way better off using VBA for stuff like this.

EDIT:

In the unlikely event you wanted to actually do something like this, you'd run into the length limit of what `EVALUATE` can handle. You'd have to chop up your longer strings into less than 65 values, not use "dummy", etc., but it would still be doable.

Comment: Huh, the evaluate() function exists in excel 2010 :( No fun for me, i guess. I'll probably be shackled to VBA for this particular problem then, but thanks for the info.

Comment: @blendmaster, the same functionality exposed by the Excel 4 macro function `EVALUATE` is also exposed by the VBA method `Application.Evaluate`. Again, just FYI...